# mssql 2008 increasing id value every minute

Tags: sql-server, identity

I created primary key in my table

```
[id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
```

I noticed that id increasing about an every minute in last week. I'm using to check increasing:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Issue');
```

I can't find any trigger or something else. And I don't create and removing records in table. Could this be an error with MsSql?
I'm using MsSql 2008 R2.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*my database create id not a sequence number*"

Comment: My database does not increase the value of the id of 1. I get a strange values of id like 3000, then 3120, then 3822, then 5326. I can't find the reason.

Comment: What version of MSSQL are you using?

Comment: I am using MSSQL 2010

Comment: There is no such thing as "MSSQL 2010" - there is SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2008 R2, SQL Server 2012...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be related to `transaction rollbacks`. Rollback will remove the data rows included in a transaction but it does not reset the identity value to its previous setting

check this

```
CREATE TABLE #ident 
( 
      ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) 
      , column1 VARCHAR(20) NULL 
) 

INSERT #ident 
VALUES ('a'),('b'),('c')


BEGIN TRAN 
INSERT #ident 
VALUES ('d'),('e'),('f')
ROLLBACK TRAN

INSERT #ident 
VALUES ('g'),('h'),('i')

select * from #ident
```

and result is

```
ID  column1
--  -------
1   a
2   b
3   c
7   g
8   h
9   i
```

so whenever a transaction is rolled-back identity wont be reseted

Answer (score 0):

There can be situation that you added some rows and then delete.
After doing that, id will be added 1 in last row id which is deleted.

Comment: But I get difference between id like 1000 ! This is a very big value.

Comment: Yes...This is big difference. I did it many times But this problem never happened with me.

Comment: @Paul see https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to check is that any new stored procedures are correct. I've ran into situations where people had scripted out changes and forgot a `GO` in between two parts, so the second part was included in the stored procedure. We were mysteriously getting records added to a table. It took a while to catch it.

In your case, it may be doing something  (like seeding the data in the table), but a transaction is causing it to rollback.